# rebar3 install plugins failed

Tags: erlang, rebar3

**Env: `rebar 3.6.0 on Erlang/OTP 21 Erts 10.0 Ubuntu 16.04`**
When I try to install the rebar3 pulgins (such as rebar3_hex), it reports:

`===> Package <<"rebar3_hex">> not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...
===> Updating package registry...
===> Plugin rebar3_hex not available. It will not be used.`

There is only one line in my `~/.config/rebar3/rebar.config`: 
`{plugins, [rebar3_hex]}.`
as recommended in https://www.rebar3.org/docs/using-available-plugins#hex-package-management and https://github.com/tsloughter/rebar3_hex.

I can't get more useful information from google, rebar3 doc and existed question here.

So, I open a new question to ask Why and How to resolve it.

ps: I use proxychains for rebar3, it reports `|DNS-response| repo.hex.pm is 151.101.54.2

inet_gethost[10708]: WARNING:Malformed reply (header) from worker process 10709.`

Comment: Have you tried to install rebar 3.6.1 ? seems like this issue was fixed in the latest version

Comment: @Eugen Dubrovin, I have tested on rebar3.6.1, nothing different.  It seems like cause by proxy releated issue ?

Comment: In my case, it's fixed when set proxy environmental variable instead of use proxychains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, it's fixed when set proxy environmental variable(http_proxy) instead of use proxychains.